# knockout.js signal r getall is not function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, signalr

I am trying to implement [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/322154/ASP-NET-MVC-SignalR-and-Knockout-based-real-time-U) example

```
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

<div id="div1">
    <textarea data-bind="value: commenttext"></textarea><br />
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: addcomments" style="margin-bottom:4em">Send</a><br /><br /><br />
    <ul data-bind="foreach: comments,visible: comments().length > 0">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text:commentdate"></span>          
            <strong><span data-bind="text: commentsname"> </span></strong><br /><br />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My chatHub class

```
 public class chathub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }

    public void GetAll()
    {
        List<CommentsViewModel> boards = new List<CommentsViewModel>();


            CommentsViewModel b = new CommentsViewModel();
            b.commentid = 1;
            b.commentsname = "a";
            b.commentdate =System.DateTime.Now;
            b.cardid = 1;
            boards.Add(b);

            CommentsViewModel bb = new CommentsViewModel();
            bb.commentid = 2;
            bb.commentsname = "b";
            bb.commentdate = System.DateTime.Now;
            bb.cardid = 1;
            boards.Add(bb);
            Clients.All.taskAll(boards);
    }
    public bool Add(Comment newComment)
    {

        Comment commentobj = new Comment();
        commentobj.comment = newComment.comment;
        commentobj.commentdate = System.DateTime.Now;
        commentobj.cardid = newComment.cardid;

        Clients.All.addComm(commentobj);
        return true;
    }
}
```

my viewmodel

```
var viewModel = function () {
                var self = this;
                this.hub = $.connection.chathub;                
                self.commenttext = ko.observable();
                self.comments = ko.observableArray();
                self.commentdate = ko.observable();
                self.commentsname = ko.observable();

                self.init = function () {
                    self.hub.getall();
                }


                self.hub.addComm = function (c) {
                    self.comments.unshift({
                        commentid: c.commentid,
                        commentsname: c.comment,
                        cardid: c.cardid,
                        commentdate: c.commentdate
                    });
                };

                self.hub.taskAll = function (allcomments) {
                    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetComments", "Home")?id=" + self.selectedcard(), function (data) {
                         self.comments(data);
                     })
                }


                        self.addcomments = function () {
                            var t = { "comment": self.commenttext(), "cardid": self.selectedcard() };
                            $.ajax({
                            url: "@Url.Action("AddComments", "Home")",
                            type: "post",
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            data:  JSON.stringify(t) ,
                            success: function (data)
                            {
                                self.hub.add(t).done(function () {
                                    console.log('Success!')
                             //   }).fail(function (e) {
                             /       console.warn(e);
                                });
                                //self.comments.unshift({
                                //    commentid: data.commentid,
                                //    commentsname: data.comment,
                                //    cardid: data.cardid,
                                //    commentdate: data.commentdate
                                //});
                                // self.commenttext("");


                            }
                        });
                    };     

             };

            var vm = new viewModel();

            ko.applyBindings(vm);

            $.connection.hub.start(function () { vm.init(); });
```

Why i am getting this error ?

> ncaught TypeError: self.hub.getall is not a function
>       at viewModel.self.init (About:92)
>       at hubConnection.fn.init. (About:168)
>       at hubConnection.fn.init. (jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:546)
>       at hubConnection.fn.init.dispatch (jquery.js:4732)
>       at hubConnection.fn.init.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4544)
>       at Object.trigger (jquery.js:7788)
>       at jQuery.fn.init.triggerHandler (jquery.js:7878)
>       at jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:614
>       at jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:1114
>       at Object.success (jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:1450)

Comment: You have this.hub, but in init you use self.hub. that could be a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the hub methods are case sensitive. You should change your javascript to:

```
self.hub.getAll();
```

Dennis1679 has highlighted a useful way to check the required case in the comment below.

Comment: You can check what kind of methods are created by the hub on the server side and see the name they use. In this case you would see something like  `proxies['chathub'].server = { getAll: function () { ....` by browsing to the /signalr/hubs, so you know that it is case sensitive and you should use getAll() when calling the method.